# GridView: RegisterStartupScript on RowCommand

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm building a GridView derivate control that has edit buttons with the possibility to open a new url for edit or open a modal window (via jquery dialog) for the edit url. The thing is the javascript opening the modal window isn't firing (it might be that it fires but I can't see it because of the postback, but a console.log does not appear so I think is not firing).

The javascript code is correct, if I paste it in console it does what expected.

So this is my code in Sub:

```
Protected Shadows Sub RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles MyBase.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "EditInForm" Then
        If Not FormularioModal Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url_edicion, True)
        Else
            'Must open a modal windows, registers JS to open dialog
            Dim scriptModal As String = scriptAbreModal(url_edicion) 'This function creates correct javascript

            log.log(String.Format("Registering {0}", scriptModal))

            Dim page As Page = HttpContext.Current.Handler
            Dim nombreScript As String = "scrAbreModal" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString().GetHashCode().ToString("x")
            Dim cstype As System.Type = page.GetType
            Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = page.ClientScript

            If (Not cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(cstype, nombreScript)) Then
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType, nombreScript, scriptModal)
            End If
    End If
End If
```

*(also tryed with `RegisterClientScriptBlock` instead of `RegisterStartupScript`)*

Just for the record, the javascript code generated is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var miVentanaModal; 
miVentanaModal = $('<iframe id="iGridViewModalIFrame" src="q_pregunta_elementodoc.aspx?op=upd&id=28&pregunta=6&modal=true" />')
.dialog({ title: 'Title', 
            autoOpen: true, 
            width: 575, 
            height: 320, 
            modal: true, 
            resizable: true, 
            autoResize: true, 
            overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: "black" } }).width(555).height(300);
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

PS: this code is in a pure code class, it's in a dll that contains some controls and utilities

Comment: Is the script contained in the response of the RowCommand postback? And how so?

Comment: This code is inside de RowCommand Sub, I don't know what you mean by the "response" but it's in this Sub. The line `Dim scriptModal As String = scriptAbreModal(url_edicion)` creates the javascript code as a String and the line `cs.RegisterStartupScript` is supposed to register and execute it. Thanks

Comment: Actually, it registers the script to be executed when the request response gets to the browser, as all the page's javascript is executed by the browser only.

Comment: Yes, but apparently this script is not executing or it's executing before a new postback so I can't see it